# html forms that update in real time

Tags: html, forms

I'm not sure what to ask for, but I'm looking to create a form using html (html5?) that when numbers are inputted in can update on the same page results, works just like an excel doc. For example to have 3 fields with numbers (1, 2, 3) and for the results to sum and average the results which would be 2, but if the user changed the 1st number (7,2,3) it would update the results to 4. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: It's easy enough to do with Javascript. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Yeah... choose your language and then do the logic there. Javascript is probably the quickest and easiest client-side means of doing it(as Mike said in a sense).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this, maybe?

```js
function addNumbers(){
  
 var input1 = Number(document.getElementById('input1').value);
 var input2 = Number(document.getElementById('input2').value);
  
 document.getElementById('output').value = input1 + input2;
  
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="addNumbers()" id="input1" placeholder="enter a number"><br />
<input type="text" onkeyup="addNumbers()" id="input2" placeholder="enter another number"><br />
<input type="text" id="output" disabled>
```